# Parametrizing $(2x+y)^2(x+y)=x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, curves, plane-curves, parametrization, implicit-function

I need to find $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$ so that the implicitly defined curve on $\mathbb R^2$ $$(2x+y)^2(x+y)=x$$ is converted into an explicit function of the parameter $t$ that can be analysed using single variable calculus.

The usual parametrization $x(t)=t$ and $y(t)=xt$ yielded a very complicated form that was hard to work with. Could you help me with finding a better parametrization? Polar coordinates also didn't help much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y+2x=u$ therefore $$u^2(u-x)=x\\x=\dfrac{u^3}{1+u^2}$$let $u=t$ therefore $x=\dfrac{t^3}{1+t^2}$ and $$2x+y=t\\\dfrac{2t^3}{1+t^2}+y=t\\y=t\dfrac{1-t^2}{t^2+1}$$and we have$$(x,y)=\left(\dfrac{t^3}{1+t^2},t\dfrac{1-t^2}{t^2+1}\right)$$

Comment: You could add that this curve is defined for any real $t$.

Comment: Yes you're right but parametric descriptions often reveal any of those properties automatically.......

Comment: There is actually an error in the algebraic manipulation, $y=t-2x=t\frac{1-t^2}{t^2+1}$, not $y=t\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1}$ Otherwise, the solution is great.

Comment: Thank you @mathearts!